# Trouble connecting to mysql because it is looking in the wrong location

Tags: mysql, bash, unix, osx-lion, macports

When I try to connect to mysql which I installed using MacPorts, I get this error

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (20)`

When I run `which mysql`, I get this output `/opt/local/bin/mysql.`

How to I rectify this situation? I am running on Mac OSX Lion

Comment: First port of call: Try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` or vice versa

Comment: When I do that I get this erro: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Comment: it's trying to connect through socket not tcp; that's the usual error message telling mysql is not running

Comment: The `mysqld` binary is not what it needs to open to connect. The `mysql` client needs to connect to the socket which the server creates. The socket path looks correct, so I'll let someone more knowledgeable help you find the real problem.

Comment: Ok but when I use localhost, I get the error above

Comment: tcp here is no matter; you run client and it exits with 'cannot connect to socket': thus, server not running. Run it with *sudo /opt/local/bin/mysqld_safe5 &* then try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this page](http://2tbsp.com/content/install_and_configure_mysql_5_macports) has the answer; search for "can't connect".

And may be http://ocdevel.com/blog/mycnf-order-precedence